# Sql: select count and also many other fields in one query

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, insert, count

I am using Sql Server 2008 r2.

I have the following tables: Family, FamilyChild, Scale, Allowance.

I need to retrieve the number of children per family in order to select the appropriate value in the Scale table and then insert this value with many other fields (from these or other tables) in the Allowance table.

I need to do this for each family row in the family table.

How can I do this as simple as possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: Most probably with a stored proc... what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried to select the family id, the count with group by family id and then using union select but that's not the way because I want to use the count in order to select the appropriate value in the Scale table for each family with other fields let's say the family adress and the child birth. Perhaps I can do this with a join select but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that every row on `FamilyChild` represents one child:

```
SELECT  F.FamilyID,
        COUNT(*) NumberOfChildren
FROM Family F
LEFT JOIN FamilyChild FC
    ON F.FamilyID = FC.FamilyID
GROUP BY F.FamilyID
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to select the count and also the appropriate value in the Scale table depending on this count and also many other fields like for example the Family File Number and the Child Birth.How can I do that with Union or in another way ?

Comment: @BIY How would I know?, you haven't provided any details about the tables definition. At these requirements are also not on your question. If that's what you want, then explicitely tell us what is the **exact** result that you need, and what are the columns in your tables

Comment: In the Scale table there are amount fields : amount for 1 child, amount for 2 children, amount for 3 children ... I need to select the correct amount with the family address in family table and the Child birth in the ChildFamily table.

Comment: @BIY Look, it's not that hard to properly explain the columns you need. For instance, you named `Child Birth`, is that a date?, if so, how will you retrieve that if there are multiple children?, you want one column per children?, because you also wanted the total number of children as a column

Comment: Yes it's a date and I need it for every row in the FamilyChild table ( for every child).

Comment: @BIY So, you want one column per child on your result set. That's why I asked you (more than once) to post your desired result so we don't have to guess what it is that you want. This requirement isn't **anywhere** on your question, and it definitely makes this a different question than the one you posted

Answer (score 0):

Without the fields of the tables (and thoses needed to join the tables, you will not have a very appropriate answer. All I can say is: use a count() with the group by operator:

```
select f.family_name, count(c.children_id) 
from family f inner join familyChild c on f.family_id = c.family_id
```

Then you can join this with the scale table or use it in and EXISTS subquery to filter the scale table and do your insert.

Comment: Thanks, I need to select the count and also the appropriate value in the Scale table depending on this count and also many other fields like for example the Family File Number and the Child Birth.How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

while using aggregate functions like count,max you should use group by clause with select statement and the columns which are not participated in aggregate function should be group by clause....for example

```
select f.family_name, count(c.children_id) 
from family f inner join familyChild c on f.family_id = c.family_id
group by f.family_name
```